# How to round off both angles of CollectionViewCell equally?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Now, when i round off, i get one rounded and one sharp angle[image: Now, when i round off, i get one rounded and one sharp angle]

My code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 50
}
```

How can i round all angles equally?

Comment: you are doing at the wrong time, you would need to do this _later_ in the lifecycle – when the size of your view has been detemined – for example: `override func layoutSubviews() { self.layer.cornerRadius = 50 }`

Comment: seems like your cell is cust from leading and trailing. please fix width of cell and problem solve

Comment: Thank you, @RajaKishan. But i need to cell's width was the full width of the screen. That's why i control its parameters with this: 
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 280)
    }
What can i do?

Comment: You need to pass collection view width so your cell it's not go out side the collection view. ```return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 280)``` for full width also set collection view leading trailing to zero to device edge. You can check your issue by making false to clip to bound of collection view

Comment: Thanks, it helps